# RWD theme's product 'More View' results in un-zoomed small images

Tags: product, zoom

I have a site www.buyme24seven.co.uk using the RWD theme. It all works well except when a product is selected. The main product image appears fine. However when I select a 'more view' image it is shown but as a small thumb nail and not a bigger image in the main product box as it should.

Can anyone help me please. I have looked at several of the posts here but cannot seem to get this fixed. Please go to the site and see the problem as it is running.

I really would appreciate any help the community can provide me here.

Answer (score -1):

Upload same size image for product if you really want to thumbnail small images in your project then you can use resize function for resize image as you like.